# redirect bots and crawlers via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

**Hi** , well my problem that I want to redirect bots and crawlers to site5 and real visitors to site4 as you can see in this schema

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3oFd.jpg

what I did
I created a .htaccess file and put it in site1.com/folder/ :

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.com/xyz/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and I did the same in site2.com to redirect to site4.com

Did I miss something?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm a bit confused, does the code you've written not work? What is the issue you need help with exactly?

Comment: Hi  oxguy3 thank you fpr your reply , it works but I need help to apply the schema above via .htaccess ,

Comment: I'm still confused, you said it works but you need help to apply it? What do you mean by apply it?

Comment: Im sitll missing something as you can see in my code facebookexternalhit/1.1  , but facebook crawlers still pass to site4.com

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your apache setup functions correctly.

After that you could try something like

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site3.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site4.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To test you can use a simple curl to simulate a google bot request:

```
curl -A "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)" http://site3.com
```

Or to get the headers only

```
curl -X HEAD -i -A "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)" http://site3.com
```

Comment: thanks for ur help but my code not working maybe if I edit it to : RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(110\.174\.129\.147|203\.217\.17\.162)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Googlebot|msnbot|Surp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

Comment: can you please rewrite it with this code ?